# c++ finding Static Base Address/addresses module of process runing on virtual machine emulator

Tags: c++, pointers, kernel, emulation, radix

Lets say there is a Emulator ( LDPlayer) currently running a process, And I wrote a c++ program that modifies the memory of this process with kernel driver, On different emulator i could manage to get the PID of the active process on the emulator by chasing the highest process active threads on current process,

but this emulator is different, and you cannot find any other threads running just its the same .exe,

with pattern scanning this process i can normally find the address i want to modify its value

but whenever i run the process again, the address changes and the base address of the value, we are talking only of .exe emulator, so my main question how could i find the static base address of my main address value ? there is only 1 address with this value on the actual process, but this address always change when run the VM process from scratch ( emulator ) because of different addresses on memory, and searching for 0x00000 to 0x7fffff will find this address but its too much runtime to search all process memory, i want to just make it a range of the current address is it possible to find the static ranges for the address that always changes?

hopefully helpful answers.

Comment: If you aren't satisfied with pattern scanning, one option would be to reverse engineer the emulator and find out which LDPlayer function launches the android app. And get the module base address at this point. This can be a lot of work. I'd just inject a dll that would pattern scan and fetch me the address.

Comment: @user I want to pattern scan an aob value, but i need to find the actual static range that aob value is in, because it always have a new address when u run the ldplayer